# How to convert the array

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How to convert below list into LINQ? where QueueDataSource is the ArrayList.

```
         switch (queue.QueueTypeID)
        {
            case (int)QueryType.DataEntry:
                dataEntryQueue.QueueDataSource.Add(new
                {
                    QueueID = queue.QueueID,
                    LinkText = queueName,
                    Uid = sentinel
                });
                break;
            case (int)QueryType.Sort:
                sortingQueue.QueueDataSource.Add(new
                {
                    QueueID = queue.QueueID,
                    LinkText = queueName,
                    Uid = sentinel
                });
                break;
            case (int)QueryType.CaseList:
                myQueue.QueueDataSource.Add(new
                {
                    QueueID = queue.QueueID,
                    LinkText = queueName,
                    Uid = sentinel
                });
                break;
        }
```

Comment: LINQ is used with strongly typed collections such as `List<T>`. ArrayList is a weakly typed collection. Also I do not see how LINQ would help you in this situation. LINQ'a for querying data. In the code example you have shown you are adding elements to a weakly typed ArrayList.

Comment: So how to convert into List<T> ?

Comment: By using `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking in the question.  If it's to be able to access the ArrayLists using Linq then use the Linq `Cast<T>()` or `OfType<T>()` methods, e.g.

```
dataEntryQueue.QueueDataSource.Cast<QueueItem>().Where( q => q.QueueID == 1 ) ...
```

Alternatively as stated above get rid of the ArrayList and use `List<T>`.

In both cases you will need to define the QueueItem class and use that in place of the anonymous type in your code.

Otherwise @yBee's answer would seem to be what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code where `source` is an enumerable for `queue`:

```
dataEntryQueue.QueueDataSource.AddRange((from queue in source
                                         where queue.QueueTypeID == QueryType.DataEntry
                                         select new {
                                                        QueueID = queue.QueueID,
                                                        LinkText = queueName,
                                                        Uid = sentinel
                                                    }).ToList());
```

And similarly for other two array lists.